# How do I bind mount a fuse mountpoint?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fuse

I am bind mounting a fuse mount point and when I kill the fuse process, the target mount point gives me this error:

`Transport endpoint is not connected`

When I restart the fuse process, while I can access the original fuse volume, I still get the same error on the target bind mount.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that when you 'restart' the fuse process, a new mount is created (the old fuse connection is no longer valid), which is why you are getting ENOTCONN. The only way would be to umount and bind mount again.

Comment: Why would the original mount point work then?  Any bind mount options that I can use so that it continues to see the actual directory?

Comment: When you kill the fuse process, the original mount is no longer there (verify that mount(8) no longer shows the mount or ps aux|grep <your fuse mount process> is not there ). If you restart it, it might be creating a new mount.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to (recursive) bind the parent mount with mount propagation enabled (Systemd default). If done before the fuse filing system is mounted that can even simply use the same path.